# Ninject injecting wrong type

Tags: dependency-injection, ninject

I have a class with a property of type `ICollection<object>` that I'm trying to inject with an instance of type `ObservableCollection<object>`. If I obtain an instance via `Get<>` Ninject gives me the correct type, but if I get it to inject it into a class it creates a `List<object>` instead. Can anyone explain to me what's going on?

```
using Ninject;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace NinjectTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();
            kernel.Bind<MyClass>().ToSelf();
            kernel.Bind<ICollection<object>>().To(typeof(ObservableCollection<object>));

            ICollection<object> foo = kernel.Get<ICollection<object>>();
            ICollection<object> bar = kernel.Get<MyClass>().Collection;

            Debug.Assert(foo is ObservableCollection<object>); // ok
            Debug.Assert(bar is ObservableCollection<object>); // fails
        }
    }

    public class MyClass
    {
        [Inject] public ICollection<object> Collection { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is per the "[Multi Injection](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Multi-injection)" feature.
When you try to inject an array `[]`, an `IEnumerable<T>`, an `ICollection<T>` or an `IList<T>` it is always interpreted as `GetAll<T>` - so it will create an instance of each binding for `T` and return it as the "collection" type you've requested.

So far what i've done is create specific interfaces like:

```
public interface IFooCollection : ICollection<Foo>
```

and then ctor-inject an `IFooCollection`. This way you work around the multi injection feature.
Of course you could also create an interface for the observable collection:

```
public interface IObservableCollection<T> : ICollection<T>, INotifyCollectionChanged
```

Comment: Ok, that would certainly explain it. Didn't realize multi-injection is used in those cases, although now that I think about it it does make sense. My original code is now fixed, thanks for the explanation.